# Searchform and results on just one page, not two. Solutions?

Tags: php, search

I've been learning some PHP and MySQL from a book that teaches you how create a simple database driven site. In the book's examples, we're creating a joke database that store author names, joke text, date and id. Progressing I've been taught how to use includes in my main controller, index.php. I'm stuck at a part where they tell me to create a search feature for the joke database, coding as follows:

This is the first part of the controller called 'index.php' all it does is display the search form.

```
// Display search form
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';
include 'searchform.html.php'; //CHANGE 1
?>
```

The next part of the controller builds the SQL and then sends it to jokes.html.php, fairly simple... no problems here.

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) and $_GET['action'] == 'search')
{
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';
//Build SQL statement and output results into an array code here
}
include 'jokes.html.php'; //CHANGE 2
exit();
}
```

How would you modify the code above if the your searchform.html and jokes.html are just the single html file? I find it inconvenient using 2 files for searching.

My first attempt (I've merged searchform and jokes into "jokesearch.html.php") was to include 'jokesearch.html.php' in CHANGE 1 and again in CHANGE 2, however that didn't help... it just reloaded the page.

2nd attempt was to use header('Location: .')... no luck here too it just reloaded.

EDIT: By popular demand, I'll include the two html files.

searchform.html.php:

```
<?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .
'/includes/helpers.inc.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Manage Jokes</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type"
content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Manage Jokes</h1>
<p><a href="?add">Add new joke</a></p>
<form action="" method="get">
<p>View jokes satisfying the following criteria:</p>
<div>
<label for="author">By author:</label>
<select name="author" id="author">
<option value="">Any author</option>
<?php foreach ($authors as $author): ?>
<option value="<?php htmlout($author['id']); ?>"><?php
htmlout($author['name']); ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<label for="category">By category:</label>
<select name="category" id="category">
<option value="">Any category</option>
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
<option value="<?php htmlout($category['id']); ?>"><?php
htmlout($category['name']); ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<label for="text">Containing text:</label>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text"/>
</div>
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="search"/>
<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</div>
</form>
<p><a href="..">Return to JMS home</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

jokes.html.php

```
<?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .
'/includes/helpers.inc.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Manage Jokes: Search Results</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type"
content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Search Results</h1>
<?php if (isset($jokes)): ?>
<table>
<tr><th>Joke Text</th><th>Options</th></tr>
<?php foreach ($jokes as $joke): ?>
<tr valign="top">
<td><?php htmlout($joke['text']); ?></td>
<td>
<form action="?" method="post">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php
htmlout($joke['id']); ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit"/>
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete"/>
</div>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
<p><a href="?">New search</a></p>
<p><a href="..">Return to JMS home</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just curious, what is the reason to give `.inc.php` and `.html.php` extensions?

Comment: Can you paste the content of the includes into your question?

Comment: No problems. The book says giving them names allows me to identify the file types easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a MVC perspective your initial setup is the right way to go.
Your controller collects and processes data and sends it to views (your .html.php files).

It is good practice to separate defferent elements into different views. So a search box or search results go in a different view than the jokes.

Putting both logical different elements in one view file makes maintenance harder.

Regards,
Erwin Vrolijk
snow.nl

Comment: Yes, I would agree on the maintenance... but unfortunately I need it all in one file. Take for example a pizza order search/results page with 3 columns: 1 for search form, another for results and last for order or a cart. You would want to display them at the same time.

Comment: You can display them at the same time, in your case using multiple include statements. The reload probably happens because of some code whitin the included file. Check if there are no headers or meta-tags set from whitin the included files.

Comment: You aren't using a MVC pattern here. These files are templates which are invaked by some kind of dispatcher. The term controller doesn't really fit here. Making this work requires a lot of explanation and example code, perhaps you should can look through your book and find some more information, or to get started with a real MVC framework check the documentation of the Zend Framework.

Comment: I see, there is absolutely no way I can whip up a html to do this? The book unfortunately doesn't tell much... I've only been learning PHP and MySQL for a week, using Zend would probably be too much :P I find it odd that PHP can't even do such a basic thing...

Comment: It absolutely can be done! The point is in your example, the included files are complete html files, including html headers and footers. This must be changed to dynamically building the html page, starting with the head, doing some computation in your 'controller', adding different views to the output and closing with the html footer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this

if (isset($_GET['action']) and $_GET['action'] == 'search') {
// search result
} else {
// show search form
}

Comment: I've tried your method... no luck with it. Just refreshes itself with no data input. Thanks for replying anyways.